# Django allauth custom template not hashing passwords

Tags: python, django

I am using my own custom view and inheriting from `SignupView` (in `from allauth.account.views import SignupView`) I am also using my own forms.py to pass on to my custom view. It is signing up the user just fine, but one thing it's not doing is hashing the passwords. It's saving the passwords for the user the way it is. How can I make it so that the passwords are stored in the table as a hash?

**forms.py**

```
from .models import User
from django import forms

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']

    username    = forms.CharField(label='Username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username:'}))
    email       = forms.EmailField(label='Email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email:'}))
    password    = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password:'}))
```

**views.py**

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView
from .forms import RegisterForm

class RegisterView(SignupView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'oauth/auth_form.html'
```

**project urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('oauth.urls')),  //app name I created where my custom sign up view is
    url(r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls')),

    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form needs to inherit from `SignupForm` because its `save()` method is using the correct way for creating new users. When you just use a `ModelForm`, the `save()` method will create a new `User` object using normal initialisation of models, whereas `User` creation needs special treatment for the password.

So just define the fields and change `password` to `password1`:

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm

class RegisterForm(SignupForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username:'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email:'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password:'}))
```

Comment: No, you don't have to, the allauth `SignupForm` already defines all the required fields. Note that if you only use one password to signup, you need to set `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False` in your settings.py otherwise your form will validate for a repeated password field.

Comment: I do get an error saying `ValueError: ModelForm has no model class specified.` when I don't add the meta information. Also, when I do add the meta information what happens is the password field becomes a regular input field for some reason

Comment: Also, I thought we were supposed to inherit from SignupForm so why are we doing forms.ModelForm?

Comment: Also it's worth to note that I am using a custom User model that's inheriting the django.contrib.auth User model

Comment: If you specify `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.User'` in your settings, you shouldn't see that error.

Comment: Sorry, stupid mistake, copy&paste and then forgot to update the inheritance.

Comment: For some reason I am getting this error: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing form class oauth.forms: "cannot import name 'SignupForm'"`

Comment: You're sure you're importing from allauth.account.forms?

Comment: Yes, I've imported exactly the way you have written.`Here's some of the error: File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\views.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .forms import (
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\forms.py", line 239, in <module>
    class BaseSignupForm(_base_signup_form_class()):
  File "C:\python3.6.3\lib\site-packages\allauth\account\forms.py", line 221, in _base_signup_form_class
    ' "%s"' % (fc_module, e))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing form class oauth.forms: "cannot import name 'SignupForm'"`

Comment: Did you define `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` in your settings? This errors occurs when that cannot be found. You don't need to define it actually, because you've overriden the `SignupView` which gets the right form already.

Comment: Yes I did, I defined it like this: `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'oauth.forms.RegisterForm'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162408/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-user2896120).

Comment: When I try to enter a non unique username during sign up I get `%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists.` and the variables are not there

Answer (score 0):

You can do by overriding `save`

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']

    username    = forms.CharField(label='Username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username:'}))
    email       = forms.EmailField(label='Email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email:'}))
    password    = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password:'}))

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if instance.password:
            instance.password = make_password(instance.password)
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: This would work, but also defeat the purpose of `allauth` on the long run, since allauth is using authentication adapters to create the user. If you want to add a 3rd party authentication for signing up (like Facebook or Google), you really want to inherit from allauth's  `SignupForm`